# How to prove that $M^G=\mathbb{F}_p[x_1\cdot v, x_1^{p\cdot(p-1)}+ v^{p-1}]$?

Tags: gr.group-theory, galois-theory, group-cohomology, invariant-theory, modular-representation-theory

Let $G=Sl_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$ and $M= \mathbb{F}_p[x_1,x_2]$, where $p$ is a prime.

$M$ is a $G$-module with $(A\cdot x_1, A\cdot x_2)=(x_1,x_2)\cdot A, (\forall) A \in Sl_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$.

I have to show that

$$M^G = \mathbb{F}_p[x_1\cdot v, x_1^{p\cdot(p-1)}+ v^{p-1}],$$

where

$$v=x_2\cdot(x_2+x_1)\cdot(x_2+2\cdot x_1)\cdots(x_2+(p-1)\cdot x_1 )$$ and

$$M^G=\lbrace m\in M \mid g\cdot m= m, \forall g\in G\rbrace.$$

I posted [on M.O.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/279197/how-to-show-mg-mathbbf-2x-1-cdot-v-x-12-v) and M.S.E. the particular case when $p=2$ but I didn't recive any idea.

Comment: The question for $p=2$ was posted here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/279197/how-to-show-mg-mathbbf-2x-1-cdot-v-x-12-v

Comment: Perhaps it's worth noting that $v = x_{2}(x_{2}^{p-1} - x_{1}^{p-1})$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $R$ be the ring that you think is equal to $M^G$.  You need to check that $R$ is fixed by $G$ and that $M$ is a free module of rank equal to $|G|$ over $R$.  Then Galois theory tells you that the field of fractions $QR$ is $(QM)^G$.  Moreover, as $R$ is a polynomial ring it is a unique factorisation domain and so is integrally closed in $QR$, and from that you can deduce that $R=M^G$.  If you search for "Dickson invariants" you will find more details (usually written for $GL_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$, but the special linear cases is similar).